# Biholomorphism between balls of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following subsets of $\mathbb{C}$:

$A = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-a| < r \right\}$ and $B = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-b| < r' \right\}$

And I have to prove if it is true that are biholomorphic.

As both of them are simply connected I think that there are biholomorphic so I think about the following biholomrphism:

$f: A \rightarrow B$

$\hspace{0.7cm} z \rightarrow r'\frac{z-a}{r}+b$

But I dont know if is correct.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct, since your map is biholomprphic. You wrote that such a map should exist, since both $A$ and $B$ are simply connected. That is not correct: $\Bbb C$ and $D(0,1)$ are simply connected, but there is no biholomorphic map between them. On the  other hand, you don't even have to know what “simply connected” means in order to prove that your map $f$ works indeed.